# How to replace spaces with %20 in <img> tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to replace all spaces in the image tags of a html text.

Example:

```
<img src="photo 1.jpg" />
```

to

```
<img src="photo%201.jpg"/>
```

I didn't find a soultion with preg_replace, but it may be a simple regexp line. 
Thanks!

**Edit**: Sorry guys, my description was not very clear. So, I have a **full html page** and I only want to replace inside the img tags. I can't use urlencode here as it encodes the other stuff as well.

Comment: Can you give us a code sample, or a more detailed idea of what you've tried?

Comment: I tried some simple things like preg_replace("/\s/", "%20"...), but it obviously replaces all spaces in the text. There must be a way to tell php to only replace inside the src='' parts, but I don't know how.

Comment: use urlencode to encode urls.  use preg_replace to do less "there is a built in object that does that" type stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space is represented by a %20 in the url but there are other chars that you might want to have converted for other images so you should use the general urlencode function instead of using a "simple regex" as stated in the OP.

```
<img src="<?php echo urlencode('file name.jpg'); ?>"/>
```

Comment: `urlencode()` will replace space by `+` , `rawurlencode()` is the correct function that fits the purpose.

Comment: I didn't even notice lol. You did post a better answer than me :)

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**

I may have missed the point, if you are not scanning over already written out HTML, this probably is not for you. This is for if you were scrapping it for whatever reason. I am leaving it up for pure nostalgia as it could help someone else who wants to scrape and replace. Sorry for the confusion.

---

Since you know the tags and the attribute, I would suggest looking into the [PHP DOM](http://php.net/dom) to do this. Regex can do it, but the DOM would be preferred and perhaps bit easier / more reliable, given the context you are looking at. This will scan the generated HTML and allow you to replace items inside of attributes (in this case `src`) that with using the [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/rawurlencode) you can get the spaces converted to %20.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// $dom->load('test.html'); // if in a file
$dom->loadHTML($html); // if in a string

for ($i=0; $i<$dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->length; $i++) {
    $encoded = implode("/", array_map("rawurlencode",
         explode("/", $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')
                    ->item($i)->getAttribute('src'))));

    $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')
            ->item($i)
            ->setAttribute('src',$encoded);
}


echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Worked on my small test file, just an example of how it could be done :)

Comment: @brad Almost correct, but you need [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode) to get %20 instead of + for space encoding.

Comment: +1. This will correctly handle `<img src="photo&#32;1.jpg">` and such as well.

Comment: @ikegami, probably not. It may be possible to use the `basename` to just get the actual filename or perhaps `explode`. If needed the OP can expand this code to do what is needed :) Thanks for bringing that up though, as it was easily overlooked.

Comment: @Brad F Jacobs, I'd provide a solution, but I don't know PHP. In Perl, `$src = URI->new($src)->as_string;` would do (and `->as_string` can be omitted).

Comment: To clarify @ikegami's comment, `rawurlencode` will only handle file names properly. If passed a path such as "images/hello world.jpg" the "/" would be encoded as well and lead to a 404.

Comment: Added a fix for the path. This will not take into account url's preceded with an HTTP:// etc., but should work if the relative path is used.

Answer (score 4):

this is what you need `rawurlencode();`

[php.net/rawurlencode](http://%20php.net/rawurlencode)

Comment: `rawurlencode` and `urlencode` will only handle file names properly. If passed a path such as "images/hello world.jpg" the "/" would be encoded as well and lead to a 404.

Answer (score 2):

Hey,
I've found a simple solution, using preg_replace_callback. I've never heard of this function before, but it's great.

Posting the code here:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback("/src=[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"]/", "removeSpaces", $text);
function removeSpaces($matches) {
  return "src='" . str_replace(" ", "%20", $matches[1]) . "'";
}
```

Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following may work:

```
$img_src = 'images/some crazy image.jpg';
$img_src = preg_replace('/ /g', '%20', $img_src);
echo '<img src="' . $img_src . '" alt="some image" />';
```

But it's a bit hard to tell since you didn't give us any details about why `preg_replace` didn't work, what its output was, etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks. You are right, I should have given more details. 

I have a full html page in a php variable, $text. There are all kinds of html elements in there. I want to replace all the spaces in the image urls, inside all the img tags.

Comment: just wanted to note that the `/g` modifier is unnecessary and does nothing since there is no global modifier in PHP (it's global by default): http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php